# WSO2 BPS The operation is not declared on porttype

Tags: wso2, bpel

I have a simple Bpel process which invokes an end point on ESB. I am using WSO2 ESB, BPS 3.0.0, Gov Reg and App server. But the deployment of the bpel process is failing with error message:
BPEL Process Compilation Failure.    More
    2013-07-16 14:41:19,721 null:145: error: [UndeclaredOperation] The operation "null" is not declared on portType "{http://}*****ProxyPortType".

Does any one knows what might be going wrong here?

Comment: I can't say for sure without the code, but it sounds like you are missing the specification of an `operation`, most likely in a `receive` or `invoke` activity.

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the bpel process along with external service wsdls, if the problem is not yet solved. 
-Thanks